# How to change the color of \faQuestionCircle in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, color, fontawesome

How to change the color of \faQuestionCircle in Beamer?

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}

 \faQuestionCircle Is there a question?

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The characters in `fontawesome` are, as the name suggests, glyphs of a font, so the usual commands for changing the color of the text will work. Also, `beamer` already loads `xcolor`, so no additional packages are needed:

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}

\textcolor{red}{\faQuestionCircle} Is there a question?

{\color{blue} \faQuestionCircle} Is there another question?

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]